# How do I center a window on the screen in C# & WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, screen, center

I need a way to center the current window on the screen.

So for example, if a user pushes a button, I want the window to center itself on the screen.

I know you can use the startposition property, but I cannot figure out a way to use that other than when the application first starts up.

So how do I center the form on the screen?

Comment: I suppose you using win forms?

Comment: Do not use Form.CenterToScreen. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837463/how-come-centertoscreen-method-centers-the-form-on-the-screen-where-the-cursor-i/6837499#6837499) for details.

Comment: use the CenterToScreen() Method in the constructor of the form class.

Comment: try: `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;` OR   `this.CenterToScreen();`

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Use [Form.CenterToScreen()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen.aspx) method.

Comment: On system with two monitors the form will be centered on one that currently have the cursor. So, the form may suddenly jump to other monitor. See the post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837463/how-come-centertoscreen-method-centers-the-form-on-the-screen-where-the-cursor-i/6837499#6837499).

Comment: The documentation you reference does say "Do not call this directly from your code." though it doesn't say why.

Comment: The documentation does say use the form's StartPosition property to center it. It worked for me.

Comment: This works, I just had to instantiate it: this.CenterToScreen();

Comment: I would also like to know why the documentation says "Do not call this directly from your code."

Comment: This won't work if placed after this line of code: ```this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Location;```

Answer (score 189):

1. Using the *Property* window

   Select form → go to property window → select "start position" → select whatever the place you want.

   [image: "]
2. Programmatically

   `Form form1 = new Form();
   form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
   form1.ShowDialog();`

   **Note:** Do not directly call Form.CenterToScreen() from your code. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen.aspx).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since it only centers the form at startup, not when pressing a button.

Answer (score 46):

A single line:

```
this.Location = new Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2,
                          (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2);
```

Comment: This shows a good way of getting the center of *either* the 'x' or 'y' manually. I needed 'center screen', but only for the 'y' coordinate.

Comment: Why Screen.PrimaryScreen? What if the form is on 'SecondaryScreen'? You should use `Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this);` here.

Comment: I use this primitive techniques simply because it works on **.NET Compact Framework 3.5**, and this also explain why I don't use `Screen.FromControl(this)` but keep it to `PrimaryScreen`. (I'm developing an application under hardware constraint) :-)

Comment: That method is ok if you are only using one screen. However, if you have multiple monitors and click a shortcut over here on the left monitor, you don't really want it opening on the right one. The StartPosition property handles that for you.

Comment: This is not [per monitor DPI aware].

Answer (score 38):

In Windows Forms:

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

In WPF:

```
this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
```

That's all you have to do...

Comment: Best answer for the situation. I did not want to set the position but to have it reset once I came back to the form. This is perfect.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to center your windows during runtime use the code below, copy it into your application:

```
protected void ReallyCenterToScreen()
{
  Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this);

  Rectangle workingArea = screen.WorkingArea;
  this.Location = new Point() {
    X = Math.Max(workingArea.X, workingArea.X + (workingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2),
    Y = Math.Max(workingArea.Y, workingArea.Y + (workingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2)};
}
```

And finally call the method above to get it working:

```
ReallyCenterToScreen();
```

Comment: This works best since it will work even if you run ```this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Location;``` before it, other answers do not work in such case of moving app when using multiple screens.

Comment: This worked on my machine with 3 monitors.

Answer (score 9):

**Centering a form in runtime**

1.Set following property of Form: 
    
   -> StartPosition : CenterScreen
    
   -> WindowState: Normal

This will center the form at runtime but if form size is bigger then expected, do second step.
2. Add Custom Size after InitializeComponent();

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Size = new Size(800, 600);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
this.CenterToScreen();  // This will take care of the current form
```

Comment: -100. "**Do not** call CenterToScreen() directly from your code. Instead, set the StartPosition property to CenterScreen."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen.aspx

Answer (score 6):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace centrewindow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
            public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
            public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
            public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CentreWindow(Handle, GetMonitorDimensions());
        }

        private void CentreWindow(IntPtr handle, Size monitorDimensions)
        {
            RECT rect;
            GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(this, handle), out rect);

            var x1Pos = monitorDimensions.Width/2 - (rect.Right - rect.Left)/2;
            var x2Pos = rect.Right - rect.Left;
            var y1Pos = monitorDimensions.Height/2 - (rect.Bottom - rect.Top)/2;
            var y2Pos = rect.Bottom - rect.Top;

            SetWindowPos(handle, 0, x1Pos, y1Pos, x2Pos, y2Pos, 0);
        }

        private Size GetMonitorDimensions()
        {
            return SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Centers any window you can get the handle of

Answer (score 6):

Might not be completely relevant to the question. But maybe can help someone.

Center Screen non of the above work for me. Reason was I was adding controls dynamically to the form. Technically when it centered it was correct , based on the form before adding the controls.

So here was my solution. ( Should work with both scenarios )

```
int x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - this.PreferredSize.Width;
int y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - this.PreferredSize.Height;

this.Location = new Point(x / 2, y / 2);
```

So you will notice that I am using "PreferredSize" instead of just using Height / Width. 
The preferred size will hold the value of the form after adding the controls. Where Height / Width won't.

Hope this helps someone .

Cheers

Comment: This is a great response! and should be the solution to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Working sample

```cs
private void barButtonItem1_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    AccountAddForm f = new AccountAddForm();
    f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    f.Show();            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Location property of the form. Set it to the desired top left point

desired x = (desktop_width - form_witdh)/2

desired y = (desktop_height - from_height)/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` to retrieve the size of the primary monitor (or inspect the `Screen` object to retrieve all monitors). Use those with `MyForms.Bounds` to figure out where to place your form.

Answer (score 0):

In case of multi monitor and If you prefer to center on correct monitor/screen then you might like to try these lines:

```
// Save values for future(for example, to center a form on next launch)
int screen_x = Screen.FromControl(Form).WorkingArea.X;
int screen_y = Screen.FromControl(Form).WorkingArea.Y;

// Move it and center using correct screen/monitor
Form.Left = screen_x;
Form.Top = screen_y;
Form.Left += (Screen.FromControl(Form).WorkingArea.Width - Form.Width) / 2;
Form.Top += (Screen.FromControl(Form).WorkingArea.Height - Form.Height) / 2;
```