# How come CenterToScreen method centers the form on the screen where the cursor is, not the screen with the focused app?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am using Visual Studio 2010, C# .NET 4, WinForms.  My PC has 2 monitors.

When I call the `CenterToScreen` method of a form, the form centers itself on whichever screen the cursor is on.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen.aspx):

> Do not call this directly from your code. Instead, set the
>   StartPosition property to CenterScreen.
>
> The CenterToScreen method uses the following priority list to
>   determine the screen used to center the form:
>
> 1. The Owner property of the form.
> 2. The HWND owner of the form.
> 3. The screen that currently has the mouse cursor.

So, effectively it's used during the initial showing of the form. It's not intended to be used later.

You could write your own like so:

```
protected void ReallyCenterToScreen()
{
    Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this);

    Rectangle workingArea = screen.WorkingArea;
    this.Location = new Point() {
        X = Math.Max(workingArea.X, workingArea.X + (workingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2),
        Y = Math.Max(workingArea.Y, workingArea.Y + (workingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2)
    };   
}
```

Comment: I do have the `StartPosition` set to `CenterScreen', but the form size may change automatically when data is loaded, and I wanted to re-center it.  Thanks for the documentation snippet above.  Its all so clear now.  =)

Comment: @Welton - Added example to show how you can always center to the current screen. Adapted from CenterToScreen via ILSpy.

Comment: Eureka!  Thanks @CodeNaked.  I had originally attempted similar logic (height & width, divided by 2, blah, blah, blah) before I came across the `CenterToScreen` method, but I couldn't figure out how to identify the screen on which the application was currently located.  The 'Screen.FromControl' is the ticket!  Now it all works as expected.  =)

Answer (score 4):

Its by design:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen.aspx

Comment: True, but that wasn't the question :-)

Comment: You asked if anyone knows why a form centers on the screen that has the cursor on it ;p  MSDN knows why.... It does it because it is by design which is point three in the link. (The screen that currently has the mouse cursor.)