# Windows Form Cannot be Displayed CenterScreen

Tags: c#, .net

I used this code for the secondary form to act / be like mdi, this is windows form C#

```
        frmFontLoad fontLoad = new frmFontLoad();
        
        fontLoad.TopLevel = false;
        Controls.Add(fontLoad);
        fontLoad.Show();
        fontLoad.BringToFront();
```

but the result then the form was loaded is like this refer to screenshot:

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We1zQ.png)

Code on Form Load:

```
  private void frmLabelPNInput_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            Printer_SerialPort = new SerialPort(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Printer_com_port"]);

            btnOk.Enabled = false;
        }
```

how can i make this secondary form to be displayed at the center?

Comment: Setting the StartPosition property in the Load event is too late.  But setting TopLevel to false is the core problem, the form no longer behaves like a form anymore.  It is strongly similar to a UserControl, the StartPosition property no longer has any affect.  Nor does it in any way resemble an MDI child.  Like a UserControl, you have to set its Location property to get it where you want it.

Comment: are you want to display your window center screen of windows display or parent screen ?

Comment: this link has multiple solutions for showing center screen 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601827/how-do-i-center-a-window-onscreen-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        frmProgress progress = new frmProgress();
        progress.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - progress.Width) / 2;
        progress.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - progress.Height) / 2;
```

This solved my problem, thanks